# Is it possible to set session.gc_maxlifetime > 65535 seconds

Tags: php, session

Currently my `session.gc_maxlifetime` is set to default, thus 1440 seconds.

I would like to set the `maxlifetime` to a month, 4*7*24*60*60 seconds. However, I've read on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#107990) that the maximum value of `session.gc_maxlifetime` is 65535.

Is it therefor impossible to set my `maxlifetime` to more than 65535 seconds?

Comment: Are you sure this is actually the maximum value? The info in the manual is a user comment. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45871) higher values are possible.

Comment: I am interested in what problem you are trying to solve by delaying the 'garbage collection' for so long.

Comment: @Vatev - Thanks for the link. Does the maximum depend on the session.save_handler? From what I understand from scottmac@php.net it could.

@Ryan Vincent - Right now I have set my `session_set_cookie_params(4*7*24*60*60)` in my phpinfo() I read that the `session.cookie_lifetime` is indeed this value. However after 24 minutes (the maximum lifetime set by `session.gc_maxlifetime`) kills it.

Comment: what information are you keeping in the session that needs to be there for a long time?

Comment: I don't want the user to login again every day.

Comment: It depends on the save handler because the handler stores the data and does the garbage collecting. Also extending the session lifetime is not the correct solution to your problem. The default behaviour of most browsers is to remove the session cookies when the browser is closed. There are several tried and tested ways to make persistent logins, look around and pick one that fits your requirement.

Comment: Ok, then store the fact that the user logged in in a separate cookie. do not store the 'remember me' details in the session. For a really good explanation see this **stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication#477579**

Comment: Great comment! Thanks! Indeed much better than prolonging the session cookie lifetime

Comment: I have a cookie set only by users of a progressive web app and I don't want them ever logged out even if their session is considered "garbage" by not logging in after a few weeks.

Comment: Permanent session is not solution for your task. Check chapter PART II: How To Remain Logged In - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication#477579

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible, if you do self session handler

then PHP garbabe collector will not handle your sessions

```
session_set_save_handler()
```

see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: This isn't really the question. it's regarding this comment php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#107990 stating that the maximum value of session.gc_maxlifetime is 65535.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that by using cookies.

```
      setcookie("gc_maxlifetime", YOUR COOKIE VALUE, time() + YOUR 
    REQUIRED TIME);
      if(isset($_COOKIE['gc_maxlifetime']))
     {
    $_SESSION['gc_maxlifetime'] = $_COOKIE['gc_maxlifetime'];
       }
```

now this way the session becomes the cookie and will expire when the cookie expires.

Comment: Yeah of course you can set it to this value, that's not the question you can set the value of maxlifetime various config files too. Its regarding a comment in the php docs stating that 65535 seconds is the maximum value or errors occur. Check out the docs.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#107990 this is the question